# Get single record with nuxt.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, nuxt.js

I cannot get a single record to display in a nuxt.js mongo express app.

**the api** request below returns a 200 response in postman and gets the record by id as expected

```
// Get Single Report
router.get('/:id', async (req, res) => {
  const reports = await loadReportsCollection()
  await reports.findOne({_id: new mongodb.ObjectID( req.params.id)})
  res.send(await reports.find({}).limit(1).toArray())
  res.status(200).send()
  }
)

async function loadReportsCollection() {
  const client = await mongodb.MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/reports/', {
      useNewUrlParser: true
  })
  return client.db('monthlyreport').collection('reports')
}
```

The link to single record in pages/reports/index.vue is

```
<NuxtLink :to="{ name: 'reports-id', params: { id: report._id } }">
   {{ report.month }}
</NuxtLink>
```

and the request on the frontend in pages/reports/_id.vue is below but does not return a record - the error is

> "GET http://localhost:5000/api/reports/undefined
>   net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE"

```
<script>
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      report: {}
    }
  },
  async asyncData({ params }) {
    const { data } = await axios.get(
      `http://localhost:5000/api/reports/${params._id}`
    )
    return { report: data }
  }
}
</script>
```

Why is the ID undefined?

Comment: Your `params._id` is `undefined` (I think do not have any `report` has id is `undefined`). In backend side, just call `res.send`(res.json....) once time to finish a request. You can use `findOne ` method to get single mongo document.

Comment: you should use params.id instead of params._id